# Get mail from one email account while sending from another in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I have two mail accounts added to Thunderbird. One is Hotmail, the other Gmail. I want to set up the following:

- The Hotmail account to be the only one to receive emails on Thunderbird
- The Gmail account to be the default account for sending emails.

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately Thunderbird separates sending and receiving accounts.

What you want is just the Hotmail account set up in Thunderbird, but set up the GMail account to be the sending account.

If you go to the account settings you see something like this:

[image]

Make sure the only account listed is the Hotmail one, and then select the Outgoing Servers section.

In there you will probably have both the Hotmail and GMail listed.  Just remove the Hotmail account from there.

Now all email will be sent from GMail, and you will only be able to receive the email in Hotmail.

It seems a bit of a strange setup to be honest, but what the customer wants, the customer gets...

Comment: Thank you! I said exactly the same. But he's used to it so i won't question his options.

Comment: I suppose if he's migrating from Hotmail to GMail it kind of makes sense... all email to his 'old' hotmail account gets replied to from his 'new' GMail account.

Comment: The thing is... he's not. He wants everything to go to hotmail (gmail redirects to it) because he was used to MSN email alerts (go figure...) and he wants to send most of his emails from the gmail account... you know.. musicians...